# Isomorphism of vector bundles and covering homotopy theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I am trying to understand the proof of the following corollary in Hirsch's Differential Topology :

> Two $C^r$ vector bundles $\eta_0$ and $\eta_1$ over a paracompact base space $B$ are $C^r$ isomorphic if and only if there is a $C^r$ vector bundle $\eta$ such that $\eta_i \cong (\eta|_{B\times i })$, $i=0,1$.

Now I am having touble with $\Leftarrow$. By the covering homotopy theorem we know that $\eta \cong (\eta|_{B\times 0})\times I$, but I don't know what to do with this, I am a bit confused with the isomorphisms that are going on.

Any help with this is aprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do we construct that isomorphism of bundles? It has to cover the identity map, right?

Comment: Are you asking about the proof of the covering homotopy theorem ?

Comment: I guess. I can’t seem to find a clear modern statement of it...